# Aplicación Spring Boot a veces no responode a una solicitud HTTP

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

Tengo una API REST desarrollada con Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE y funciona bien, puedo acceder a los diferentes recursos HTTP sin problemas. Pero sucede que en ocasiones (las cuales no he logrado predecir ni encontrar un patrón común) cuando intento consumir un recurso (no importa cual) desde una aplicación cliente desarrollada con Java 11, utilizando el nuevo HTTP Client, el servidor no responde a la solicitud (y el código del controlador nunca llega a ejecutarse), lo que provoca que se bloquee. He hecho muchísimas pruebas y en una de ellas establecí un timeout tanto para la conexión

```
HttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

como para la solicitud

```
HttpRequest.newBuilder(new URI(url))
           .requestBuilder
           .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(5));
```

y pude darme cuenta de que no hay problema estableciendo la conexión con el servidor sino en la solicitud, que pasado el tiempo definido me lanza la excepción `HttpTimeoutException` (que si no defino timeout no se lanza y se bloquea la aplicación indefinidamente).

Realmente no tengo ni idea del porqué de este comportamiento, porque como dije, no es predecible ni está relacionado a un controlador en específico.

PD: La aplicación la he desplegado tanto en Tomcat 8.5.x como en 9.x. Además también he probado creando un WAR y desplegar en una instancia independiente de Tomcat o creando un JAR y ejecutándolo con un servidor embebido.

Alguna idea?

**EDITADO**

Controlador de ejemplo

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/common")
public class CommonController {

    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/hospital")
    public ResponseEntity<List<HospitalDto>> getLoadAllHospitals() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(adminService.findAllHospitals());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola!, podrias poner mas detalles de tu clase o de un controlador que te este dando estos problemas

Comment: Es irrelevante el código, puesto que el problema ocurre en cualquier controlador y nunca llega a ejecutarse el código de estos. De todos modos acabo de agregar un ejemplo.

Comment: Solo quería ver el uso de tus anotaciones, haciendo pruebas con postman obtienes los mismos resultados? como envias las peticiones desde el cliente?

Comment: Es difícil probar con Postman porque no es algo que pueda garantizar que ocurra, es muy aleatorio. Incluso una de la pruebas que hice fue poner un Thread desde la misma app cliente a tirar solicitudes y no ocurrió.

Comment: Ya veo y que tal los logs de Tomcat? no marcan algo fuera de lo normal? Usas un servidor proxy como nginx?

Comment: Los logs de acceso de Tomcat no registran nada cuando ocurre el problema. He seguido haciendo diferentes pruebas y al parecer el problema está relacionado con el Java 11 HTTP Client y/o la configuración para que este utilice SSL.

Comment: Puedes mostrarnos como mandas la petición desde el cliente? es raro que funcione aveces si y aveces no, si realizando pruebas con Postman en todas responde bien lo unico que se me ocurre es que el problema este ahi, te preguntaba sobre Tomcat ya que a mi me ha pasado que deja de responder cuando hay un desbordamiento de memoria o peticiones muy pesadas a una base de datos no se si sea al caso, podrías probarlo monitoreando tu aplicación con VisualVM, Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Me ha pasado en un par de oportunidad un error parecido, este error me da cuando trato de deployar 2 proyecto en mi servidor local, y no pueden verse a si mismo, para solucionar este problema agregue el siguiente tag a mi RestController.

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin 
public void pruebaController prueba{
}
```

CrossOrigin es un mecanismo que utiliza encabezados adicionales HTTP para permitir que un user agent obtenga permiso para acceder a recursos seleccionados desde un servidor, en un origen distinto (dominio), al que pertenece.